# How to capture response from Cancel or Ok Button in two different Applications?

Tags: vb.net

With my Application (vb.net) I am trying to scan Excel files some of which have ActiveX Components.

When running my Application, I am getting a pup-up window in Windows Vista Environment with Office-2007 having button OK and Cancel button to proceed.

But my problem is the scanning is not proceeding even after I keep on pressing the **OK button**. Now I want to continue with my application while pressing the **Cancel button**; i.e. just to skip the file. Is it possible to capture the response from the **cancel button**? (As this is a message box from another application, i.e. either from Vista or Office-2007, I'm not sure).

My main motive is to just ignore the message box to proceed....

Can anyone please help me out there....

Thank you....

Answer (score 1):

The `DisplayAlerts` property of `Microsoft.Interop.Excel.Application` may help here.

If set to `FALSE` then Excel automatically chooses the default option on pop-up boxes. 
Whether or not this applies to ActiveX controls I don't know but it may be worth trying.